# Finding the force of acceleration on an attractive body

Tags: c++, physics

I have a simulation with a planet orbiting a star. The equation for force on the planet is:

G⋅M<sub>1</sub>⋅M<sub>2</sub>⋅(q<sub>1</sub>−q<sub>2</sub>)/||q<sub>1</sub>−q<sub>2</sub>||<sup>3</sup>

Where G is the gravitational constant, M<sub>1</sub> and M<sub>2</sub> are the masses of the star and planet, and q<sub>1</sub>−q<sub>2</sub> is the difference between the position vectors of the two bodies.

I have converted this equation into component form where

F<sub>x</sub> = G⋅M<sub>1</sub>⋅M<sub>2</sub>⋅(x<sub>1</sub>−x<sub>2</sub>)/||q<sub>1</sub>−q<sub>2</sub>||<sup>3</sup>

F<sub>y</sub> = G⋅M<sub>1</sub>⋅M<sub>2</sub>⋅(y<sub>1</sub>−y<sub>2</sub>)/||q<sub>1</sub>−q<sub>2</sub>||<sup>3</sup>

with x<sub>1</sub>−x<sub>2</sub> being the difference between the x component of the vectors, and y<sub>1</sub>−y<sub>2</sub> being the difference between the y components of the vectors.

The ||q<sub>1</sub>−q<sub>2</sub>||<sup>3</sup> can be rewritten as sqrt((x<sub>1</sub>−x<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup>+(y<sub>1</sub>−y<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>3</sup> which can we rewritten as ((x<sub>1</sub>−x<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup>+(y<sub>1</sub>−y<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>3/2</sup>

This is my code

```
    xdif = (planets[0].x - stars[0].x);
    ydif = (planets[0].y - stars[0].y);

    planets[0].ax = -10*xdif / pow((pow(xdif, 2) + pow(ydif, 2)), 1.5);
    planets[0].ay = -10*ydif / pow((pow(xdif, 2) + pow(ydif, 2)), 1.5);
```

For some reason, the planet does not follow an orbit like it should. Does anyone know what I got wrong?

EDIT::
Forgot to mention, all of these variables are doubles, and the language is c++

EDIT 2:: Here is the complete code

```
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

    #include <math.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <chrono>
    using namespace std;
    #define SCREEN_WIDTH  1920
    #define SCREEN_HEIGHT 1080
    #define LGREY RGB(200,200,200)
    #define BLACK RGB(0, 0, 0)
    #define WHITE RGB(255,255,255)

    WPARAM w;
    HINSTANCE hInst;
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    POINT mousePos;
    int t;
    struct star { double x, y; };
    struct Body { double x, y, vx, vy, ax, ay; };
    star stars[2];
    Body planets[1];
    long newtime= std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    long oldtime=newtime;
    int signx;
    int signy;
    double force = 0;
    double xdif;
    double ydif;

    void drawCircle(int x, int y, int w, int h, COLORREF insidecolor, COLORREF bordercolor, HDC hdc) {

        HGDIOBJ B1 = CreateSolidBrush(insidecolor);
        HPEN P1 = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, bordercolor);
        SelectObject(hdc, B1);
        SelectObject(hdc, P1);
        Arc(hdc, x, y, x + w, y + h, x - 1, y - 1, x + 1, y + 1);
        DeleteObject(B1);
        DeleteObject(P1);

    }

    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
        mousePos = { 1200, 600 };
        WNDCLASSEX wc;
        ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

        wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";
        wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(WHITE);

        RegisterClassEx(&wc);

        HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"WindowClass", L"Template", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 10, 10, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

        hInst = hInstance;

        //separated by 10 au
        stars[0].x = 0;
        stars[0].y = 0;
        stars[1].x = 10;
        stars[1].y = 0;
        planets[0].x = -5;
        planets[0].y = 0;
        planets[0].vx = 0;
        planets[0].vy = -1;
        planets[0].ax = 0;
        planets[0].ay = 0;

        ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);


        MSG msg;
        bool running = TRUE;
        while (running) {
            if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
                if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
                    running = FALSE;
                }
            }
        }
        return msg.wParam;
    }
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc;

        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            planets[0].x += planets[0].vx;
            planets[0].y += planets[0].vy;
            planets[0].vx += planets[0].ax;
            planets[0].vy += planets[0].ay;

            xdif = (planets[0].x - stars[0].x);
            ydif = (planets[0].y - stars[0].y);

            planets[0].ax = -10.0*xdif / pow((pow(xdif, 2) + pow(ydif, 2)), 1.5);
            planets[0].ay = -10.0*ydif / pow((pow(xdif, 2) + pow(ydif, 2)), 1.5);

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                drawCircle(planets[i].x * 50 + 1920 / 2 - 10, planets[i].y + 1080 / 2 - 10, 20, 20, BLACK, BLACK, hdc);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {//1920x1080
                drawCircle(stars[i].x*50+1920/2 - 25, stars[i].y+1080/2 - 25, 50, 50, BLACK, BLACK, hdc);
            }
            while (newtime < oldtime + 10000000/60) {//60 frames per second
                newtime = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
            }
            oldtime = newtime;

            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

With Visual C++ 2015 it can be compiled as follows (with console subsystem, suitable for testing a malfunctioning application):

```
cl orbit.cpp -D UNICODE gdi32.lib user32.lib kernel32.lib /link /subsystem:console /entry:WinMainCRTStartup
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match the gravitational equation.  Why do you have an exponent of `1.5` when the equation has `3`, and what happened to `M1` and `M2`?  Also, watch out for your operations which might be getting cast to `int`, e.g. `-10*xdif`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain that, I'll edit it in a second. Essentially, ||x1-x2||^3 can be rewritten as sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)^3 which can we rewritten as  ((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)^(3/2)

Comment: Ok, so is there any way to rewrite ||q1-q2||^3 to work with euclidean space?

Comment: Also, I replaced the constants with 10 for simplicity

Comment: Please provide a *complete* (but minimal) example that readers can copy and paste to reproduce the problem. For example, you might have a loop that steps through one orbit period and asserts that the planet ends up in roughly the initial position.

Comment: Ok, the simulation is part of a GUI, so I'll upload it with that included if that's OK.

Comment: The error might be in your handling of the constants, so you should show us that instead of using 10.  What exactly are you doing with them?

Comment: What exactly are the planets doing? It's also possible that because you're doing Euler integration, you're experiencing numerical instability.

Comment: If I used the actual constants, then it would require a year for the simulation to complete...

Comment: I don't plant to run it, I just want to see what you're doing.  For instance, if you forget to divide out the mass of the planet everything will go all wonky.

Comment: @meepzh I thought that might be possible, but in that case, I should get different results if I made the simulation slower (the integration would be more precise) and I don't

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I understand that, but because the G*M1*M2 is a constant, it should still create an orbit even with changes to the constant value

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. So could you tell us what the planets are doing right now? That could be helpful for debugging. It might be good to hunker down and do a frame or two of calculation manually, though it looks like your math is right. Edit: I ask that because it's possible your initial values for the planet aren't good.

Comment: @meepzh They are accelerating and slowing down at irregular intervals. I found the problem with my formula, and now the program works. I'll be answering the question in a sec. Thanks everyone who helped

Comment: It turns out to be the same as the force on an average-looking, or even plain ugly body.

Comment: Apparently there are two effects at play here: exceeding escape velocity, and too course-grained simulation.

Comment: Don't call `InvalidateRect` in `WM_PAINT` handle.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the formula I was using, I believe the correct way to separate the vectors is using the equation C*(q1-q2)/||q1-q2||^2

This is the code:

```
    xdif = (planets[0].x - stars[0].x);
    ydif = (planets[0].y - stars[0].y);

    planets[0].ax = -.01*xdif / pow(hypot(xdif, ydif), 2);
    planets[0].ay = -.01*ydif / pow(hypot(xdif, ydif), 2);
```

This seems to work for now, there is some instability which I think I'll be able to deal with. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming `hypot` is Euclidian distance (the hypotenuse of the coordinate triangle), then this gives acceleration proportional to distance, which is unlike our universe.

Comment: It isn't proportional to distance, it is proportional to the inverse square of distance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law

Comment: Just to note: using pow to square something calculated as a square root is a little silly: you'd be better off calculating the squared distance directly (ie `hyp=xdif*xdif+ydif*ydif`, and use hyp for both denominators.)

Comment: @sam: Proportional to inverse square of distance is our universe. proportional to inverse distance is the code above, if `hypot` is Euclidian distance. Sorry about the word "inverse" somehow slipping away there.

Comment: You are using the Euler integration scheme. It is known to be very inaccurate and unstable given large time steps. Moreover, it is not symplectic, which means it does not properly solve the Hamilton equations. There is a [symplectic form of the Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method), but it is just as unstable. Look into the [Leapfrog method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) or better the [velocity Verlet method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Velocity_Verlet).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but this won't fit in a comment.

You can use `<chrono>` in a much safer, more accurate, more efficient, and more readable manner if you make the following simple adjustments:

```
auto newtime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto oldtime = newtime;
// ...
using frames = std::chrono::duration<
                                std::chrono::system_clock::rep, std::ratio<1, 60>>;
while (newtime < oldtime + frames{1}) {//60 frames per second
    newtime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
}
oldtime = newtime;
```